# Compiler error in custom Alamofire response function

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm attempting to implement a generic `responseObject` function for Alamofire using Argo. Unfortunately I'm getting a persistent compiler error:

```
error: missing argument for parameter #2 in call
        APIManager.manager.request(APIRouter.Login(username: usernameTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text)).responseObject { (object, error) -> Void in
```

I understand this error to usually mean something about tuples, so I'm guessing something in my code is being misinterpreted as a tuple, but I can't figure out what. Here's my `responseObject` function:

```
func responseObject<T: Decodable where T == T.DecodedType>(completionHandler: (T?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
        return responseJSON(options: .AllowFragments) { (request, response, JSON, error) in
            // TODO: Complete error handling.
            var responseObject: T?
            if let JSON: AnyObject = JSON,
                let response: Response = decode(JSON) where response.status == "0" {
                    responseObject = decode(JSON)
            }
            completionHandler(responseObject, error)
        }
    }
```

My request code and router work fine, it's the addition of this `responseObject` function that breaks things.

Comment: Occasionally the error will show up as `cannot invoke 'responseObject' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> Void)'`, which would seem to be an issue with the closure, but the signatures match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to provide an explicit type to the variables brought into a closure with a generic return type. So instead of `(object, error) in` I needed `(object: SpecificType?, error)`.